# Windows binaries quit silently

Tags: windows, mysql, docker-for-windows

All mysql binaries (`bin\*.exe`) quit without a single word.

Running Windows Server 2016 as host. Running `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore` docker image inside with native Windows containers.  Unpacked `mysql-5.6.43-winx64.zip` inside the container.  None of the binaries work. For example,

```
c:\mysql\bin> mysqld.exe --help
c:\mysql\bin>
```

- No errors on the console.
- Nothing in Windows Event Application, Security, Setup, System logs mentions "mysql". (`wevtutil ... | findstr /i mysql`).
- Used `dumpbin` from Visual Studio to see `mysqld.exe`'s `/imports`, i.e. what DLLs it needs - all are present within the container.
- Tried `bin\replace.exe`, `bin\mysql.exe`, etc - all with the same result.
- Checked that both the OS and the MySQL binaries are x64 - they are, at least according to the Docker image description and mysql's zip name.

I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with MySQL specifically as I've seen this behaviour with other programs before, especially on the nanoserver.

How do I figure out the cause of the abnormal behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: The recommended way to install is using [MySQL Installer](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/). Or if from zip then there are [more steps](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-install-archive.html) to do.

Comment: @harrymc yes all of this is according to the noinstall instruction. Also exactly the same steps make it work on full Windows Server, outside the container. The problem only happens in the container.

Answer (score 1):

It was totally due to missing DLLs. When I said all DLLs were present in the container, turns out while the DLL files were indeed present, they were a wrong version or build or something, specifically `msvcr100.dll`.